# How to send Geolocation from google form?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Please I need your help here anyone. I was building a google form and I needed to add Geocode to the form so that users can send their location with the filled form. So I got this piece of code from Maxi Research ([link](https://www.maxiresearch.com/?wp_eStore_download_now=80)). I did everything right but when it got to the point the user has to click the geolocation webapp link to send location coordinates I receive the error ("**Exception: No HTML file named Index was found. (line 2, file "Code")**"

I need help to recognize what's wrong in the code. Thanks

```js
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getLoc(value) {
 var destId = FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId() ;
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destId) ;
 var respSheet = ss.getSheets()[0]  ;
 var data = respSheet.getDataRange().getValues() ; 
 var headers =  data[0]   ;
 var numColumns = headers.length ;  
 var numResponses = data.length;
 var c=value[0];
 var d=value[1];
 var e=c + "," + d ;
 
 // the script will add device geocode data in last submit data row by clicking the link on confirmation page that shows up after hitting the submit button
 // geocode data here consists of 3 columns : time to click the link, longitude & latitude and address (using reverse geocode) 
 // as long as clicking the link is done before next respondent submit button, data will be entered in the right row.
 // however particularly for the case of multiple devices that submit data at about the same time then whichever device clicks the link closer to the last submit row timestamp, their geodata will be entered in the last submit data row.
 // leaving geocode column in the row above empty. In this case the geocode data will be in red font 
 // If sometime later another device click the link then the geodata will be entered in closest missing geodata row. The data will also be in red font
 // Therefore for red font data you may want to check manually after completion for correct geodata entry. In the questionnaire add question about address to help checking.

    if (respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns).getValue()=="GeoAddress") {


//fill data for second respondents onwards no missing geo data
// time here is Jakarta, you may need to change time to your local time (in GMT)

    if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).getValue()=="" && respSheet.getRange(numResponses-1,numColumns-2).getValue()!="" ){
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-1).setValue(e);
    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
    f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns).setValue(f);    
    }

//fill data with previous geo data missing. red font

    else if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).getValue()=="" && respSheet.getRange(numResponses-1,numColumns-2).getValue()=="" ){
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).setFontColor("red");
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-1).setValue(e).setFontColor("red");
    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
    f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns).setValue(f).setFontColor("red");    
    }
    
//to fill missing previous data. red font    
    else if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).getValue()!=""){
        for (i = 0; i < numResponses; i++) {
    if (respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns-2).getValue()=="") { 
    
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).setFontColor("red");
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns-1).setValue(e).setFontColor("red");
    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
    f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses-i,numColumns).setValue(f).setFontColor("red");    
    break; }
    }
    
    }
    }
    
    else if (respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns).getValue()!="GeoAddress") {
//create labels in first row    
    respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+1).setValue("GeoStamp");
    respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+2).setValue("GeoCode");
    respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+3).setValue("GeoAddress");
//fill data for first respondent 
    if (numResponses==2) {
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+2).setValue(e);
    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
    f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+3).setValue(f);    
    }
    else if (numResponses > 2){
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).setFontColor("red");
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+2).setValue(e).setFontColor("red");
    var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
    f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
    respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns+3).setValue(f).setFontColor("red");
    }
    
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
(function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
})()
function showPosition(position) {
  var a= position.coords.latitude;
  var b= position.coords.longitude;
  var c=[a,b]
  getPos(c)
  function getPos(value) {
  google.script.run.getLoc(value);
 } 
}
</script>
<body> 
<p> GeoCode Entered </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J93uww0vMFY

Tutorial on Geotagging (Geo-stamp and Time-stamp) google forms. Add info on Latitude, Longitude, and Address (Street name and number, city, state, zip code, and country) of a device submitting google forms. Linking user’s location within google forms. Google forms integration with google maps.